# Is there always a Riemann integrable $g$ for a Lebesgue integrable $f$ so that $f = g$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Prove or disprove that if $f$ is a bounded function and Lebesgue integrable on an interval $[a, b]$, then there exists a Riemann integrable function $g$ so that $f = g$ a.e. and $\int_{[a,b]} f dλ= \int_a^b g(x) dx$.

I checked through the theorems and examples of the book and also MSE, neither could I find a counter-example nor a proof if it's a theorem. Detailed explanation as well as hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The indicator function of a Fat Cantor set $F$ may be a candidate. It is discontinuous at every point in the Cantor set (by virtue of Cantor sets not containing any open interval).

Comment: Is my explanation correct: f is Riemann integrable 
if and only if f is bounded and continuous a.e. Because measure of a fat cantor set is positive its indicator function is not a.e. continuous so it's not Riemann integrable but it is Lebesgue integrable since a fat cantor set is measurable (?)

Comment: @L.G. Yes, that fills in the remaining details.